# How to use LLGeofence framework in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, location

How **Geo-fencing** works in iPhone and how would I would like to know how can I implement framework in my app.
I want to know the structure of implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a `CLLocationManager` class, that allows you various stuff about location.

It has following methods:

```
+ (BOOL)regionMonitoringAvailable
+ (BOOL)regionMonitoringEnabled

- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
- (void)startMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region desiredAccuracy:(CLLocationAccuracy)accuracy
- (void)stopMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

after you setup region monitoring, you can receive the following callback in your `CLLocationManagerDelgate`:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

These methods are used almost the same exact way as the rest location methods are used in CoreLocation. The official docs from Apple have some info how to use them in details: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13

Comment: I asked about Geo-fencing, not CLLocationManager,

Comment: LLGeofence is a framework that provides geofencing for your mobile iPhone app. A geofence is a virtual region representing a real-world geographic area. When the user enters or exits a geofence, you're application is notified by callback.

Comment: That's exactly the same the above APIs does - you define a geo-region and get notifications when you leave them or enter

Comment: There is no LLGeofence framework. If you want to implement geo-fencing in your application use CLLocationManager, *exactly* like Denis answered.

Comment: THere is framework, I am using it, but having issues, and how I will define region in CCLocationManager?

Comment: For instantiating a CLRegion instance just use it's initializer method: - (id)initCircularRegionWithCenter:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)center radius:(CLLocationDistance)radius identifier:(NSString *)identifier - you need to know lat/long of your place, radius of your circular region and some string ID

Comment: and how it will identify, by calling these delegates, that I have entered or left the regions?

Comment: 1. You're creating regions; 2. than you're registering them in CoreLocation with startMonitoringForRegion: call; 3. then you implement your CLLocationManagerDelegate somewhere and assign it to the initialized CLLocationManager instance; 4. when device leaves or enters on of the registered regions, you're notified by the corresponding callback(s) of the delegate;

Comment: I do agree with your answer, that library is really too much expensive and not properly documented.